# asp.net core 2.1 target .Net Framework and run on IIS without hosting bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-7

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application with target framework .Net Framework 4.6.1. I would like to host it on IIS but I don't want to install .net core hosting bundle. Is it possible to run this app on IIS without installing .Net Core Hosting Bundle? I tried running this page on local IIS but I get:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

Most answers suggest installing .Net Core Hosting Bundle to fix this error, but since I am not allowed to install it on remote server I would like to know if there is any other way?

Comment: If the fact is that "since I am not allowed to install it on remote server", then you cannot use ASP.NET Core at all, and must 1) find a way to install the server bundle, 2) or switch to other technologies, like ASP.NET 4.x. There is nothing to bargain.

Comment: ASP.NET Core can be deployed self-contained and run via `Http.Sys`, so that may be an alternative option, but to use IIS as a reverse-proxy, you *must* install the hosting bundle. There is no choice in the matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publish to IIS. Omit installing .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070643/publish-to-iis-omit-installing-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle-on-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting in your package references asp.net core 2.1 (as title says) then you're basically targeting Runtime Framework that you need to have installed on your machine.

Comment: I created "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and in the dropdown selected ".Net Framework" and in the second dropdown I selected "ASP.NET Core 2.1". In project properties I can see Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: You still need to install the hosting bundle and your IIS application pool must run as "no managed code".

Answer (score 0):

Created a MVC application with ASP.NET Core 2.1 targeting .NET Framework and published the application to a folder.

Then, I managed to host the application in IIS with application pool with Integrated Pipeline and .NET CLR v4.0 as shown below:

[image]

**Important**: Next thing you need to ensure that Application pool identity user (`IIS AppPool\{ApplicationPool Name`} has `Read and execute` permissions on your publish folder.

If you check the web.config of your published app, you will notice `AspNetCoreModule` handler is referenced. This `AspNetCoreModule` is required to host the app in IIS as it act as a reverse proxy. So you need to install ASP.NET Core hosting bundle for installing this module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I set my page to use app pool ASP.NET v4.0. I added permissions to "Everyone" group just to make sure this isn't a permission issue, but still the same error. Is there any way you could add your solution to github? So I could test it on my environment?

Comment: @FCin please check your system Event viewer for any errors.

Comment: No errors, but when I look at IIS -> Basic Settings -> Test Settings, then I get "Invalid application path". My path points to "web.config" file.

Comment: So I have to install hosting bundle

Comment: The pool should still use no managed code. It is Kestrel that would run on .NET Framework, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1 which means IIS worker process can be .NET Framework free.

Comment: @FCin did you get your website working? Yes, you need to install hosting bundle.